# How to receive a broadcast for start of a download

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, android-download-manager

I'm trying to set a receiver in my manifest to listen for when a download commences, not when it completes (as soon as a user clicks a download link in his browser, for example). However, ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE is the only action I'm able to find. Here is my manifest:

```
<receiver android:name=".MyBroadcastReceiver " >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Is there a different action available which will trigger when a user clicks a download link?